# How to make child column follow parent row on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a table from the bootstrap-table plugin that gets populated with data a custom API. The table can get pretty long depending on the data that gets returned. I have several list groups that sit next to the table that will hold certain information from the table based on a users interaction with the table. If the data that populates the table causes the user to have to scroll down to view the rest of the data, I want the list group to follow the scroll.

This is the HTML. I want the column with the class of 'followScroll' the follow the table if the user has to scroll down. Its all nested within a row and the list groups are nested in the first list group column so that they can stack on top of each other. I tried using position: fixed on the 'followScroll' class, but that just made the list groups disappear. Any advice on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="row tableData mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <table id="table2" class="table table-bordered border-secondary">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true">Copy</th>
                        <th data-field="date">Date</th>
                        <th data-field="temperature">Temperature</th>
                        <th data-field="hdd">HDD</th>
                        <th data-field="meterReading">Meter Reading</th>
                        <th data-field="expected">Expected</th>
                        <th data-field="replacement">Replacement</th>
                        <th data-field="reason">Reason</th>
                        <th data-field="notes">Notes</th>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 followScroll">
            <ol class="list-group list-group-numbered">
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                    <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                        <div class="fw-bold">Subheading</div>
                        Cras justo odio
                    </div>
                    <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">14</span>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                    <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                        <div class="fw-bold">Subheading</div>
                        Cras justo odio
                    </div>
                    <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">14</span>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                    <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                        <div class="fw-bold">Subheading</div>
                        Cras justo odio
                    </div>
                    <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">14</span>
                </li>
            </ol>
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ol class="list-group list-group-numbered">
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                            <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                                <div class="fw-bold">Subheading</div>
                                Cras justo odio
                            </div>
                            <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">14</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                            <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                                <div class="fw-bold">Subheading</div>
                                Cras justo odio
                            </div>
                            <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">14</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                            <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                                <div class="fw-bold">Subheading</div>
                                Cras justo odio
                            </div>
                            <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">14</span>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
                    <ol class="list-group list-group-numbered">
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                            <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                                <div class="fw-bold">Subheading</div>
                                Cras justo odio
                            </div>
                            <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">14</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                            <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                                <div class="fw-bold">Subheading</div>
                                Cras justo odio
                            </div>
                            <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">14</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                            <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                                <div class="fw-bold">Subheading</div>
                                Cras justo odio
                            </div>
                            <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">14</span>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you try adding "sticky" property to your child element?

Comment: I did. The column just stays in its position and doesnt follow the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

in the CSS file you can add an overflow property.
css:

```
.followScroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

depending on if you wanted to scroll right/left (overflow-x:scroll;) or up/down (overflow-y:scroll)